# Pre-request script code repository

Tags: postman

Is it possible to store common javascript functions centrally for use in pre-request script?

In a "Postman Run" with several separate api calls I need to generate a new datetimeoffset for each call. Currently, I copy the getDateTimeOffSet javascript function to the "pre-request script" tab of each call.

Ideally I would have a central place to store helper function and be able to call these functions from the individual pre-request scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to re-use function in postman - is to store them as a global/environment variable. You may try to create a separate request and initiate some kind of utils module and then add it to the scope of your variables:

```
pm.environment.set('utils', () => {
    const generateRandomText = () => {
        //generate random text
    }
    const generateUsername = () => {
        //generate username
    }
    return {
        testPackage: {
            generateRandomText,
            generateUsername
        }
    };
});
```

In Pre-request scripts and Tests of other request you can simply call:

```
const utils = eval(environment.utils)();
const text = utils.testPackage.generateRandomText();
const username utils.testPackage.generateUsername();
```